# Expanding on weekdays formula to create a function

Tags: r, function, restriction

I am practicing creating functions with R and could do with some assistance.  I can get the weekdays function to work on its own but want to turn it into a function that will restrict inputted values.  Right now I have tried to limit the days between 0-31 and months 0-12 and return an error message.  Would it be very long winded to include instances such as February having 28 days, some months only having 30 days or to include leaps years?  How would it be best to approach restricting input values?

```
dayoftheweek=function(dd,mm,yyyy){
if(dd<1 | dd>31) warning("Enter a valid date")
if(mm<1 | mm>12) warning("Enter a valid date")
date=string("dd-mm-yyyy")
return(weekdays(as.Date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')))
}

dayoftheweek(12,12,2016)
```

I want to be able to enter the dates manually but the "date" line doesn't seem to link to the "weekdays" command.  I know that XX-XX-XXXX values work in the formula, so is a string the incorrect usage here?

Comment: `date <- paste0(dd, mm, yyyy, sep = '-')`.